# Delete Performance on Logging Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a logging table that records events from an application, but while attempting to delete old entries, the server slows down and holds up the application from using the database.  I'd like to be able to delete log entries older than 30 days quickly without interrupting new log events from being created or inhibiting other database operations.

**INFO:**

- The logging table inserts about 300,000 rows a day so generally it'll
  have ~10 million rows for a month of logging.
- I'm using SQL Express server on a pretty weak machine, 4gb ram
- There is a PK index on an ID field but no other indexes or foreign
  keys.
- This table isn't used for anything besides logging so no other operations are performed on it.

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogEvents](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Occurred] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Severity] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LotNo] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Code] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

Currently I have the application calling the following stored procedure every minute to clear the old logs in batches. (Let @Days = 30)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ClearLogsOlderThan]  
@Days int
AS   
DELETE TOP (4500) from LogEvents 
WHERE DATEDIFF(dy, [Occurred], GETDATE()) > @Days
```

**My Questions:**

1. Is there a better way to delete the old rows?
2. The execution plan shows the PK Index is being used but would an index on the datetime column be better because that's what I am actually comparing?
3. Does the constant deleting of old rows and inserting of new records ruin the effectiveness of the index? Would it require frequent rebuilds? New rows should always be sequential and only old rows will be getting deleted.
4. Would the following query theoretically work faster?  Comparing the execution plans shows that it would, but I'd like a second opinion.  Is there a performance hit from declaring @oldID an INT instead of BIGINT like the PK column?

**QUERY:**

```
DECLARE @oldID as int;
SET @oldID = (SELECT TOP 1 [Id]
              FROM [LogEvents]
              WHERE DATEDIFF(DY, [Occurred], GETDATE()) > 30
              ORDER BY [Id] DESC)
DELETE TOP (4500) FROM LogEvents
WHERE [Id] <= @oldID
```

Comment: do you need to clean the log table every minute? or you could do it during night when server has more free space?

Comment: @LONG The machine that this is logging data for is on a line that could potentially run 24/7.  I don't want to cause any sort of operational restriction simply because the logging needs to be cleared unless it really requires it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing the log this frequently seems a bit overkill, especially since you don't specify which 4500 rows as there is no order by on your query. But the biggest issue is that your query is nonSARGable because you have your column inside a function. Do the datemath on getdate instead and at least your query can utilize an index on the Occurred column.

I used ABS() * -1 so that any existing code will still work correctly.

```
where Occurred < dateadd(day, abs(@Days) * -1, getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks!  So I should create an index on the [Occurred] column and adjust my query to isolate the occurred column outside the function?

I didn't include the order by because I don't care which old rows are deleted first.  Could enforcing an ordering increase the speed?

Comment: No if anything it will slow it down. Why such an odd number as 4500 if you don't care which ones get deleted?

Comment: I read somewhere that deleting 5000 or more rows at once would force the whole table to lock.  So... superstition?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx

So I should be adding an index to Occurred column?

Comment: Yes I would add an index to that column. Lock escalation is a good thing and if you are deleting a bunch of data it is not a bad thing. You could always do your deletes in batches until there are no rows that need to be deleted. I have to agree with LONG above that this sounds like it should be a nightly process instead of being done every minute. Call it once a day and be done with it. This is one of those rare times where a loop can actually help due to the amount of locking.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the help. I'll modify the procedure to be run daily and delete ALL old rows in batches of 4500.